# What's causing the hauntings/possessions?

Tags: plot-explanation, paranormal-activity, paranormal-activity-3

In [Paranormal Activity 3](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1778304/), it is either alluded to or outright stated what is actually causing the hauntings/possessions that occur in the entire series.  I can't for the life of me remember if it was supposed to be a ghost, a demon, or something else.  What type of entity is supposed to be causing all of the events that are going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [**Paranormal Activity Wiki**](http://paranormalactivity.wikia.com/wiki/Demon):

> **The Demon is the main antagonist of the Paranormal Activity film series**, the demon haunts the families of two sisters, Katie and Krisiti. The Demon is then revealed to be Toby.

[**ScreenRant**](http://screenrant.com/paranormal-activity-ending-explained-2-kofi-137162/) has a summary of the entire *Paranormal Activity* movie trilogy in chronological order, with the connections between the films pointed out.